# How do I implement `Hash` for an enum with a special case?

Tags: rust

I have this enum:

```
enum MyEnum {
    Var1,
    Var2(u32),
    Var3(u32, u32),
}
```

and I want to achieve the following behavior:

```
let mut set = HashSet::new();
set.insert(MyEnum::Var1);
set.insert(MyEnum::Var1);
set.insert(MyEnum::Var2(1));
set.insert(MyEnum::Var2(2));
set.insert(MyEnum::Var3(1, 1));
set.insert(MyEnum::Var3(1, 1));
set.insert(MyEnum::Var3(2, 1));
set.insert(MyEnum::Var3(2, 2));

println!("set = {:?}", set);
// set = {Var1, Var2(1), Var2(2), Var3(1, 1), Var3(2, 1)}
```

That is, I want to change the `Hash` behavior for variant `Var3` *specifically* to depend on its first `u32` only.

Importantly, I don't want to exhaustively `match` each enum variant since I want to retain the default behavior for all other enum variants. Hence, as far as I can tell, [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297412/how-to-implement-partialeq-for-an-enum) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31835647/how-to-implement-eq-and-hash-for-my-own-structs-to-use-them-as-a-hashmap-key) are not sufficient for what I am looking for.

The solution I came up with is this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Eq)]
enum MyEnum {
    Var1,
    Var2(u32),
    Var3(u32, u32),
}

impl PartialEq for MyEnum {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            (MyEnum::Var3(a, _), MyEnum::Var3(b, _)) => a == b,
            _ => format!("{:?}", self) == format!("{:?}", other),
        }
    }
}

impl Hash for MyEnum {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        match self {
            MyEnum::Var3(a, _) => a.hash(state),
            _ => format!("{:?}", self).hash(state)
        }
    }
}
```

... and I am looking for feedback/better solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [derivative](https://crates.io/crates/derivative) crate has been built to provide automatic implementations for standard traits with support for common customizations. With this crate, you can get exactly what you want and looks like this:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use derivative::Derivative; // 2.2.0

#[derive(Debug, Eq, Derivative)]
#[derivative(PartialEq, Hash)]
enum MyEnum {
    Var1,
    Var2(u32),
    Var3(
        u32, 
        #[derivative(PartialEq="ignore")]
        #[derivative(Hash="ignore")]
        u32
    ),
}

fn main() {
    let mut set = HashSet::new();
    set.insert(MyEnum::Var1);
    set.insert(MyEnum::Var1);
    set.insert(MyEnum::Var2(1));
    set.insert(MyEnum::Var2(2));
    set.insert(MyEnum::Var3(1, 1));
    set.insert(MyEnum::Var3(1, 1));
    set.insert(MyEnum::Var3(2, 1));
    set.insert(MyEnum::Var3(2, 2));
    
    println!("set = {:?}", set);
}
```

```
set = {Var1, Var3(1, 1), Var3(2, 1), Var2(2), Var2(1)}
```

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9a54c8c1cedb4019271df56ae8fb6651).

Answer (score 9):

The [answer by @kmdreko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69187288/2588800) shows how to use a third party crate to implement the `Hash` trait. In most cases that would be the preferred way because it will require less code and you won't have to manually ensure that the [`Hash`-`Eq` contract](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html#hash-and-eq) is not violated.

Just for completeness this is how you could have implemented it manually without a third party crate:

```rust
impl Hash for MyEnum {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        match self {
            MyEnum::Var1 => {
                state.write_u8(1); // use any distinct number as an enum variant identifier
            }

            MyEnum::Var2(v) => {
                state.write_u8(2); // use any distinct number as an enum variant identifier
                v.hash(state); // hash the actual value
            }

            MyEnum::Var3(v, _) => {
                state.write_u8(3);
                v.hash(state);
            }
        }
    }
}

impl PartialEq for MyEnum {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            (MyEnum::Var1, MyEnum::Var1) => true,
            (MyEnum::Var2(x), MyEnum::Var2(y)) => x == y,
            (MyEnum::Var3(x, _), MyEnum::Var3(y, _)) => x == y,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}

impl Eq for MyEnum {}
```